# Why does "most important const" have to be const?

Tags: c++, constants

In http://herbsutter.com/2008/01/01/gotw-88-a-candidate-for-the-most-important-const/ it mentions "most important const" where by C++ deliberately specifies that binding a temporary object to a reference to const on the stack lengthens the lifetime of the temporary to the lifetime of the reference itself. I was wondering why c++ only allows the lifetime of the object to be lengthened when the reference is const and not when it isn't? What is the rational behind the feature and why does it have to be const?

Comment: I'm hoping for a quote from The Standard here, since I've never been able to quite convince myself that it *does* require the `const`. (Looking at 12.2 p4 and 5 in N3936).

Comment: So that the compiler doesn't have to verify that no paths modify the temporary before the object goes out of scope.

Comment: @BoBTFish: You're looking at the lifetime of temporaries bound to references. For the rules about how to bind them in the first place, see [dcl.init.ref] (8.5.3 in C++11). In particular, the final bullet of p5: "the reference shall be an lvalue reference to a non-volatile **const** type [or] an rvalue reference."

Comment: @BrianCain what would be wrong with modifying the temporary before it goes out of scope?

Comment: @dan: It's usually an error. If there are no side-effects to the modification, and the modification was therefore limited to the temporary, discarding that temporary also discards all effects of the modification. Why did you do it, then?

Comment: @MSalters, you might want to modify the object before passing it into another function. Or you might want to call a non-const method on the object and keep the return value from that, but discard the object. Neither of these are necessarily best coding style, but they aren't errors any more than modifying any temporary object is.

Comment: @dan: We're talking here about sub-expressions of a single statement. It's quite contrived to talk about "modify an object before it's passed to another function" because in general you don't know the order of evaluation of sub-expressions. Allowing your idea would work on one compiler and then inexplicably break on another which used the temporary before it was modified.

Comment: A non-const _rvalue_ reference will bind to a temporary and will also extend the lifetime of the temporary to the lifetime of the reference.

Answer (score 24):

Here's an example:

```
void square(int &x)
{
  x = x * x;
}

int main()
{
  float f = 3.0f;

  square(f);

  std::cout << f << '\n';
}
```

If temporaries could bind to non-const lvalue references, the above would happily compile, but produce rather surprising results (an output of `3` instead of `9`).

Comment: Interesting, I hadn't thought of that.

Comment: Why would it output 3?

Comment: This is the usual explanation, I think. What if it were allowed in copy-style initialization, but not in parameter initialization? There are already explicit vs. implicit conversions.

Comment: @0x499602D2 Because float 3.0f would be converted to temporary int of value 3 to be passed to function. Result of the function would be lost in the temporary.

Comment: Yet `void square(int &&x)` compiles and has the unexpected result. If the argument given in this answer were the case, then binding temporaries to non-const rvalue references would also be illegal.

Comment: @Mankarse Not really - you'd normally expect to call `square(int &&x)` as `square(std::move(f))` (because it wouldn't accept lvalues), which is a strong indication `f` shouldn't be inspected after the call.

Answer (score 15):

Consider the following:

```
int& x = 5;
x = 6;
```

What should happen if this was allowed? By contrast, if you did

```
const int& x = 5;
```

there would be no legal way to modify `x`.

Comment: A hidden local variable with value 5 should be created. There is no technical reason not to allow it.

Comment: @NeilKirk However, that's not something you expect from `int&`, it would be only a burden for the compiler designers, and would not differ from `int x=5`.

Comment: @tohecz but that is how const ref binding is implemented with return values from normal functions. All features are "burdens" for the compiler designers, that's not a reason for it not to be a feature!

Comment: Simple examples like these look pointless, but they can be useful when you have horrific template code where letting this little thing just compile would save a lot of work.

Comment: This answer isn't really consistent with `C++` as a whole, since it is entirely legal to do `int&& x = 5; x = 6;`.

Answer (score 1):

Note that const references can be bound to objects that don't even have an address normally. A `const int &` function parameter can take an argument formed by the literal constant expression `42`.  We cannot take the address of `42`, so we cannot pass it to a function that takes a `const int *`.

const references are specially "blessed" to be able to bind to rvalues such as this.

Of course, for traditional rvalues like `2 + 2`, lifetime isn't an issue. It's an issue for rvalues of class type.

If the binding of a reference is allowed to some object which, unlike `42`, does not have a pervasive lifetime, that lifetime *has* to be extended, so that the reference remains sane throughout its scope.

It's not that the const causes a lifetime extension, it's that a non-const reference is not allowed. If that were allowed, it would also require a lifetime extension; there is no point in allowing some reference which then goes bad in some parts of its scope. That behavior  undermines the concept that a reference is safer than a pointer.