# How to transfer QPainter? (move an object from a factory function)

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, move-semantics, qpainter

In a Qt-related code I tried to reduce some duplicated lines by the following method:

```
QPainter createPainter(const QColor& color)
{
  QPainter painter(&m_image);
  painter.setBrush(color);
  painter.setPen(color);
  return painter;
}
```

But `QPainter`'s copy ctor is explicitly deleted. It should be not not problem in c++11, but sadly it is neither moveable. Is it any reason for this or is it just an API defect?
Is it a good solution for `createPainter` (except providing move-ctor)?

- It could accept a QPainter reference, but this would decrease the meaning of the method, and would add noise to the caller's code.
- It could return a `unique_ptr` to the `QPainter`, but it would introduce overhead for heap-allocation.
- ... Any other ideas?

Thanks for your responses!

Comment: Why not to use pointers? Like: `QPointer *p = new QPainter(&m_image); ... return p;`?

Comment: I do not want to allocate the object on the heap, just for the reason of extracting three lines of code. (In that case I would use smart pointer ensure the painter is properly freed in any case)

Comment: Using smart pointers makes sense if you are going to transfer object's ownership or handle it in some other way. I don't see you need it here. And don't think that using "smart" pointers will make your code smarter.

Comment: Actually returning a pointer which must be `delete`d has a name: ownership transfer. Returning a raw owning pointer is error-prone. It was the C-like way, but not idiomatic in C++.

Comment: @titapo Check my edit. It solves your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One trick is to return by constant reference:

**Option 1:**

```
QPainter createPainter(const QColor& color) //definitely return by value
{
  QPointer painter(&m_image);
  painter.setBrush(color);
  painter.setPen(color);
  return painter;
}
```

Then do this:

```
const QPainter& painter = createPainter(const QColor& color);
```

By the C++ standard, this guarantees that no copying will happen, but the return value's life will be extended.

**Option 2:**

User shared or unique pointers. I know you said they have an overhead, but that's nothing, assuming you're not developing game engines and this is the main pipeline (and I'm sure you're not using Qt in such a game engine).

**Option 3:**

If none of these make you happy, I'll suggest the solution that I hate, just for completeness. Use macros!

```
#define CreatePainter(painter_name) \
QPointer painter_name(&m_image);    \
painter_name.setBrush(color);       \
painter_name.setPen(color);
```

To use it:

```
CreatePainter(painter);
painter.begin(); 
//...
```

EDIT:

**Option 4**:
I just learned (thanks to Quentin) that this is legal:

```
QPainter createPainter(const QColor& color) //definitely return by value
{
  QPointer painter(&m_image);
  painter.setBrush(color);
  painter.setPen(color);
  return painter;
}
```

Then this:

```
QPainter&& painter = createPainter(const QColor& color);
```

Check the reference [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lifetime). It's a new C++11 solution to extend an object's life-time without making it const.

Comment: I like option 1! Unfortunately drawing is a non-const operation, so it will not work in current case.

Comment: @titapo Then I'm gonna tell you the worst advice in the world: use `const_cast` (no! just kidding :) ). The only legitimate solution I see left is macros.

Comment: How can you avoid copying if function returns object by value (Option 1)?

Comment: @vahancho Try it yourself. It's part of the standard. People have attacked me many times because of this as it's very non-intuitive, but it's there in C++. It's called by some "most important const". [Check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23063211/why-does-most-important-const-have-to-be-const).

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist, I didn't attack you, indeed. Just asked a question. Now I got it too, thanks.

Comment: @vahancho no no, dude. I didn't say you did. I'm just stating a fact about this as I always had the habit to put a comment beside this method stating that "if you don't believe it, try it", but forgot this time :) You're welcome!

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist since you're using C++17's copy-elision guarantees [edit: actually the question is tagged c++11, so that's irrelevant :| ], why not use `Qpainter &&painter = ...` instead of an awful `const_cast`?

Comment: @Quentin It's not movable either (as given in the question, I don't know for sure). I didn't mention the copy-elision thing because the question is tagged C++11, so I assumed copy elision is not there (by the standard, not by the implementation of the compiler, which will definitely be there as an optimization).

Comment: Okay, I must be rusty -- thought that merely returning the object by value would require a copy/move even if it is not used to initialize a value. However, there'd be no moving with a `Qpainter&&`: that's a reference as well, only not `const` and able to bind and extend the returned rvalue.

Comment: @Quentin Interesting... I'm not sure it would work with `QPainter&&`, because it sounds like it'll defeat the purpose of making capturing the return value restricted to const reference. [Check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23063211/why-does-most-important-const-have-to-be-const) to see what I mean.

Comment: See [this page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lifetime) (*Temporary object lifetime*, bullet point near the bottom) -- Herb's GotW dates back to 2008, when rvalue references weren't a thing yet :)

Comment: @Quentin You mean this one: `if supported by the implementation, when passing or returning an object of trivially-copyable type in a function call expression (this models passing structs in CPU registers)`? QPainter is not trivially copyable. I haven't found anything else related to return values from a function (except for the first one, is that what you mean? It's not at the bottom...).

Comment: No, lower still: "The lifetime of a temporary object may be extended by binding to a const lvalue reference *or to an rvalue reference* (since C++11), see reference initialization for details."

Comment: @Quentin Thanks for the info. I shall try that and then add it here :)

Comment: Thank you guys, option 4 is simply solves the problem, and definitely the answer of my question. (:

Answer (score 0):

Just as idea

```
struct ColoredPainter : public QPainter {
ColoredPainter (device, color) : QPainter (device)
setBrush(color);
setPen(color);
};

...

ColoredPainter painter(m_Image, color);
```

But I don't like that idea. Looks like duplicated code parts just looks the same but it makes no sense to put it to standalone block. It will be hard to understand this kind of class or even function.