# Reference for rvalue or not

Tags: c++, c++11, reference, lifetime, const-reference

I wonder will next code work correct with v and v2 variable or these are references for temporary variables? In other words, can I capture returned rvalue by reference? I think no, but my teamlead think another way.

```
#include <iostream>

struct Foo {
  Foo(Foo&&) = delete;
  Foo& operator=(Foo&&) = delete;

  Foo() {
    std::cout << "Constructor" <<std::endl;
  }
  Foo(const Foo&) {
    std::cout << "Copy Constructor" <<std::endl;
  }
  Foo& operator=(const Foo&) {
    std::cout << "Copy  = Constructor" <<std::endl;
    return *this;
  }
  ~Foo() {
    std::cout << "Destructor" <<std::endl;
  }
};

Foo foo() {
  Foo v;
  return v;
}

int main() {
  const auto& v = foo();
  const auto& v2 = v;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I mean... throw it in the compiler and see what it says?

Comment: It works correct, but for mee it seems v and v2 variable catch references for temporary value that mean lead to SEGFAULT

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23063211/why-does-most-important-const-have-to-be-const

Comment: Binding a temporary to a const reference extends the lifetime of the temporary to the lifetime of the reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, [this works fine](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b19bc453552cf696) and its behavior is defined.

```
const auto& v = foo();
```

This binds a temporary to a reference.  The lifetime of the temporary will be extended to match the lifetime of `v`.  (Binding temporaries to const references was supported in C++03 even, before rvalue references were a thing.)

```
const auto& v2 = v;
```

This just takes another reference to the same object.  It's basically a no-op that will be eliminated during compilation.  As long as `v2` doesn't outlive `v` (which it doesn't in this case) then there is no problem.

Comment: So, the expression like `auto v& = (1 - 2)` also will correct, will it?

Comment: @voltento, no, it has to be a const reference.

Comment: @voltento If you actually meant `auto& v = (1 - 2);` then no. You can't bind a temporary to a non-const reference. It must be const. So `const auto& v = (1 - 2);` would work.

Comment: Note that `auto && v = (1 - 2)` would be also fine in C++11.